# Customized button not working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button, customization

I tried making a customized button. This picture is what I need, and in Eclipse, it is shown as this:

[image]

But when I run it on emulator, it looks like this:

[image]

This is my xml file for the customized button which is named buttonshape.xml in res/drawable folders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="18dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="#D71C72"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:endColor="#F470AC"
        android:startColor="#F470AC"
        android:type="linear" />

   <padding
       android:bottom="0dp"
       android:left="0dp"
       android:right="0dp"
       android:top="0dp" />

   <size
       android:height="100dp"
       android:width="300dp" />

   <stroke
       android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#878787" />

</shape>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/System"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:onClick="sbmtSystem"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="@string/btnsystem"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

What seems to be missing? I restarted Eclipse and emulator.

Comment: Clean it and run it on a device, may help? Check your colors aren't messing with one another, try including alpha.

Comment: one hell of a riddle :) there's no green in the xml layouts you included, should be something else...

Comment: I'm also wondering how did that happen. i tried running it on a device but the color is still green instead of pink.

Comment: It may be an overlapping color issue (don't think so or I would post an answer :P) . Make sure 2 non-transparent colors aren't laying on top of one another or make sure they aren't transparent. By default you should be fine, but to make sure try using 8 digit hex instead of 6, setting the first 2 as FF for a solid alpha.

Comment: Which version of emulator you are using?

Comment: Hi i tried your code and it works fine. Can you try it on genymotion simulator or a physical device? Also, can you post the entire xml?

Comment: I have tried it on a physical device, My android phone. But its still the same. The color is still green instead of pink. Y_Y

Comment: I did make an app which uses the green button. But that's a different app, on a different folder. And it is not installed on the emulator that I am using nor the physical device so it should not messed up.

Comment: Are you sure that buttonshape.xml is not duplicated in another drawable folder with the green values?

Comment: I did make an app which uses the green button. But that's a different app, on a different folder. And it is not installed on the emulator that I am using nor the physical device so it should not messed up.

Comment: I think you have used custom theme for your activity/application. So that it will override the view background. Are you changing any property like colorAccent or colorPrimary in your style?